# Questions most-viewed and least-liked

Tags: support, questions, statistics

I am curious about questions with lots of views but few likes.

Is it possible to generate a report that ranks questions by *likes per view*?

As an alternative measurement, is it possible to generate a report that ranks questions by *difference between views and likes*?

Comment: Likes? You mean upvote or favorite or something?

Comment: Also, you can do this using the stack exchange data explorer tool. Tons of scripty goodness.

Answer (score 6):

You can't generate a report like that on the site directly. However, what you *can* use is the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer (SEDE)](http://data.stackexchange.com/), which is a public interface to the internal site database (though, adapted for public use and updated only once a week). You can just write a few easy queries for sorting the questions as you deem fit.

Assuming with "likes" you actually mean question score (i.e. upvotes minus downvotes), a query for **sorting the questions according to their score-per-view ratio** would look something like that:

```
SELECT TOP 100 Id AS [Post Link], ViewCount, Score, 
  cast(Score AS FLOAT)/cast(ViewCount AS FLOAT) AS ScorePerView
FROM Posts WHERE PostTypeId = 1 
ORDER BY ScorePerView DESC
```

[**Try it here!**](http://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/530330)

This only gives you the top 100 questions, though. You can adapt the `TOP ...` part accordingly, or just leave it away to get a list of all questions, which might take a little while, though. You can also change the sorting criterium for starting with the worst ratio by changing the order to `ASC` at the end.

A query for sorting by *difference* between views and score would probably not make that much sense, as they are on so vastly different scales, especially when a question becomes a Hot Network Question and gets thousands of views. But you're free to play with SEDE as much as you want, with a little bit of SQL and [knowledge about the database](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2677/162011) you can gather all kinds of statistics.

---

If with "likes" you actually mean favourites, then we just have to replace `Score` with `FavoriteCount` in the above query. If that's the case, though, please note that this is an even more inaccurate notation than using "likes" for votes, since favouriting doesn't have anything to do with actually *liking* the question, it's just a completely neutral bookmarking mechanism, like your browser's "favourites".